# orderBy not working with as keyword laravel query

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using query and orderby isn't working

```
$query = Post::query()->latest();
if ($request->input('popular') == 'true') {
  $query->where('hide_search',0)->orderByDesc('viewer');
}
```

and

```
if ($request->input('popular') == 'true') {
 $query->where('hide_search',0)->orderByDesc('posts.viewer');
}
```

and

```
if ($request->input('popular') == 'true') {
 $query->where('hide_search',0)->orderBy('posts.viewer','DESC');
}
```

Comment: Can you post the queryLog?

Answer (score 0):

First the `latest()` method already applies a "order by" keyword to your query, and takes the priority. Secondly, I'm confused as to what you're trying to do, as all your if statements have the same condition. And finally, if you want to add additional clauses to your keywords inside conditional statements, you should also update your original query variable, like this:

```
$query = Post::query()->latest();
if ($request->input('popular') == 'true') {
  $query = $query->where('hide_search',0)->orderByDesc('viewer');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Analyzing your code

You have already sorted the `created_at` column using the `latest()` function. If you want to sort within this by views, it can only consider the order of views where the `created_at` values are the same.
[`latest()`](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/queries#latest-oldest) - Laravel Docs

###### Original Records

I'll show you an example:

```
posts table
------------------------------------------
ID  |  name   |  viewer  |   created_at
------------------------------------------
1   |  First  |  12      |   2022-01-01
2   |  Secon  |  8       |   2022-01-02
3   |  Examp  |  46      |   2022-01-01
4   |  Usual  |  21      |   2022-01-03
5   |  Nowus  |  32      |   2022-01-01
```

```php
$query = Post()::latest(); // order by created_at desc
```

###### Result after order by `created_at` desc

Now value of `$query`:

```
posts table
------------------------------------------
ID  |  name   |  viewer  |   created_at
------------------------------------------
4   |  Usual  |  21      |   2022-01-03
2   |  Secon  |  8       |   2022-01-02
1   |  First  |  12      |   2022-01-01
3   |  Examp  |  46      |   2022-01-01
5   |  Nowus  |  32      |   2022-01-01
```

If you perform another sorting after this, you won't be able to override the sorting applied to the `created_at` column. Instead, you can only establish a more specific order within the records that have the same date:

```php
$query = Post()::latest(); // order by created_at desc
$query->orderByDesc('viewer'); // then... order by viewer desc
```

###### Result after order by `created_at` desc AND order by `viewer` desc

Now value of `$query`:

```
posts table
------------------------------------------
ID  |  name   |  viewer  |   created_at
------------------------------------------
4   |  Usual  |  21      |   2022-01-03
2   |  Secon  |  8       |   2022-01-02
3   |  Examp  |  46      |   2022-01-01    <---
5   |  Nowus  |  32      |   2022-01-01
1   |  First  |  12      |   2022-01-01    <--- order by viewer where has same date
```

---

### Solution for get popular post

If you need the most popular post, **you don't need to sort by the `created_at`** column using the fast function `latest()`. **Instead, you can directly sort by the `viewer`** column.

###### Original Records

I'll show you an example:

```
posts table
------------------------------------------
ID  |  name   |  viewer  |   created_at
------------------------------------------
1   |  First  |  12      |   2022-01-01
2   |  Secon  |  8       |   2022-01-02
3   |  Examp  |  46      |   2022-01-01
4   |  Usual  |  21      |   2022-01-03
5   |  Nowus  |  32      |   2022-01-01
```

```php
if ($request->input('popular') == 'true') {
  // if need return with order by viewer (so, value of created_at doesn't matter)
  $query = Post::orderByDesc('viewer');
}
else {
  // else, need return with order by created at date
  $query = Post::latest();
}

return $query;
```

###### Result after order by `viewer` desc [IF $request->input('popular') WILL TRUE]

I'll show you an example:

```
posts table
------------------------------------------
ID  |  name   |  viewer  |   created_at
------------------------------------------
3   |  Examp  |  46      |   2022-01-01
5   |  Nowus  |  32      |   2022-01-01
4   |  Usual  |  21      |   2022-01-03
1   |  First  |  12      |   2022-01-01
2   |  Secon  |  8       |   2022-01-02
```